# How to perform a "silent install" of programs with custom selection?

Tags: shell, cmd, vbscript, installshield

2 days ago I receive a task to install some programs in a silent mode like **7-zip, NPP, FileZilla** and etc. The main problem is to choose components of the program which will be install or type of install.
p.s. I indicate what I talked about in link to the image below:
https://cdn1.radikalno.ru/uploads/2019/4/20/70e995c20f61bf0b31744290b2c231a6-full.png

I installed **7-zip** in silent mode use the ready script which I found in the net. As you can see in the code below indicated some of the associations (.7z,.bz2 and etc) which were added in install mode. And they added in process of the install but not after it. That what I need.

```
@echo off

:Installing
\\yourcompany.com\software\tools\7z465.exe /S

:Associate
assoc .7z=7-Zip.7z
assoc .bz2=7-Zip.bz2
assoc .gz=7-Zip.gz
assoc .tar=7-Zip.tar
assoc .tgz=7-Zip.tgz
assoc .zip=7-Zip.zip

ftype 7-Zip.7z="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe" "%1"
ftype 7-Zip.bz2="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe" "%1"
ftype 7-Zip.gz="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe" "%1"
ftype 7-Zip.tar="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe" "%1"
ftype 7-Zip.tgz="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe" "%1"
ftype 7-Zip.zip="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe" "%1"
```

Save it in a .bat file and run it. It succeeded. But I need a flexible solution to install other programs in silent mode. If there no ready solution please advice me the right way what should I do for it? Should I learn some of the programming language or something else? Thank you! Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: How to do a silent install and whether it's even possible in the first place depends on the actual installer and the installer generator that was used to create it.